# Fokker-Planck equation

Tags: differential-equations, probability-or-statistics, code-request, simulation, stochastic-calculus

Is there any package for simulation of Fokker-Planck equation in Mathematica? Or, in general for stochastic differential equations?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Does `ItoProcess` meet your needs?

Comment: @bbgodfrey Many thanks. Please give me some time to read about that.

Comment: It depends a bit on what level you want to simulate that, there are also partial differential equation models for this. See `ref/MassTransportPDEComponent#1981924737` or [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MassTransportPDEComponent.html#1981924737).

Comment: Also searching this site for `Fokker-Plank` brings up a few hits.

Comment: @user21 Thanks for your helpful comments.

Comment: @Syed Clarification from Michael E2: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58874195#58874195